# Which folder should I write to for my intermediate files, as a dev?

Tags: scripting, filesystems, directory-structure, tmp

I'm starting to write a few bash scripts for my project and they need some intermediate files or variables to be written.

I want to know which folders can I be sure of having access to when someone runs my script? Is it a common practice to use `/tmp/` ? Or should I used something else?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I find the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard document](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) invaluable when looking for this stuff.

There are a few options,

- [/tmp](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES) - 'non-permanent' temporary files
- [/var/tmp](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE) - 'permanent' temporary files
- [/var/cache](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARCACHEAPPLICATIONCACHEDATA) - 'application' transient data files

It really depends on the kind of data you're storing.

Comment: better use that what the user/environment gives you and only use /tmp etc. as fallback. (what http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79776/7784 said)

Answer (score 15):

If you need to write some temporary files that only last as long as your script or application is running, use the directory indicated by the [`TMPDIR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TMPDIR) environment variable, or if that variable is not defined, `/tmp`.

`/tmp` is cleared at boot time on some systems (sometimes it's even in RAM, e.g. by default on Solaris, and on some Linux installations), so it cannot be used for files that must survive a power failure or a reboot. `/var/tmp` can be used for files that must survive a reboot, but that may be cleaned by the system administrator from time to time. If your application needs to save files on a permanent basis, write them somewhere in the user's home directory (in `~/.programmingnoobsapp` or `~/.cache/programmingnoobsapp`)  or under `/var/lib/programmingnoobsapp` or `/var/cache/programmingnoobsapp`.

Note that `/tmp` is shared between all users, so you need to take precautions when creating a file there. You need to pick a file name that doesn't exist yet, and you need to be careful not to allow a race condition where another process creates the file ahead of you with different permissions, which could be a security hole (if the other process is running as a different user, it could then access and modify your process's data). Use the [`mktemp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp) command to create a file in `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`. By default, `mktemp` creates a file in `$TMPDIR`, or `/tmp` if `TMPDIR` is unset, which is usually the right place. If you need to use multiple temporary files, or even if you need a single one, I recommend creating a directory for all your temporary files with `mktemp -d` and removing it at the end of your script.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmp_root=
trap 'rm -rf "$tmp_root"' EXIT INT TERM HUP
tmp_root=$(mktemp -d)
tmpfile1=$tmp_root/file1
tmpfile2=$tmp_root/file2
…
```

Comment: wrt to mktemp, I do not remove temporary files at the end of my script.  I have a tmpwatch cron job which automatically removes old files.  In the vast majority of cases, I do not read the intermediate file and the system will delete the files by itself.  However, if something goes wrong with the script, I have all my intermediate files for easy debugging.

Comment: +1 for `mktemp`. For me this is the correct answer: delegate the task of safely creating a temporary file to `mktemp` (see [this article](http://www.linuxsecurity.com/content/view/115462) ). Although the one answer quoting the `FHS` has great value too.

Comment: Why do you initialize `tmp_root` before assigning it? Wouldn't it be more natural to `unset` it?

Comment: @l0b0 Either will work (except under `set -u`, but that's uncommon). It needs to be (un)set to a safe value before setting the trap, in case the script is killed just after setting the trap.

Comment: I'd add `set -o errexit` so that if `tmp_root` is already set read-only in the environment it won't destroy the wrong directory...

Comment: No `mktemp` on AIX :(

Comment: @EightBitTony `tmp_root="${TMPDIR-/tmp}/myapp-$$-$RANDOM"; mkdir "$tmp_root"` (in ksh) should do as a poor man's replacement.

Comment: Yup, know there are options, just making the point that not all UNIXes have a native mktemp.  The OP doesn't specify a distribution or UNIX type.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the answers that have already been posted thus far.

There is also `/dev/shm` on some Linux distributions which can be use for temporary storage. This storage should only be used when performance of the file I/O is a critical factor given `/dev/shm` makes use of the `tmpfs` filesystem. Also it should be used for reasonably sized files & data. The `tmpfs` filesystem makes use of a system RAM as storage so it isn't persistent from boot to boot.

There's a good overview of all the choices mentioned here on StackOverflow as well in this Q&A titled: [/tmp vs. /dev/shm for temp file storage on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745281/tmp-vs-dev-shm-for-temp-file-storage-on-linux). It's covered well in this SuperUser Q&A titled: [When should I use /dev/shm/ and when should I use /tmp?](https://superuser.com/questions/45342/when-should-i-use-dev-shm-and-when-should-i-use-tmp).

#### References

- [Wikipedia - Shared Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)
- [Wikipedia - Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)
- [Wikipedia - Tmpfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs)
- [Tmpfs - kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `/tmp` is mostly for files that are required temporarily. The /tmp has sticky bit on which mean only the item's owner, the directory's owner, or the superuser can rename or delete files. many programs use this to create lock files and for temporary storage of data. On some distribution this directory is cleared out at the bootup or shutdown.

Comment: Not all /tmp directories are cleared at boot.  For example, default AIX installations don't (and this is UNIX & Linux, not just Linux).

Comment: However, if it is "memory" resident, which seems to be default in a lot of cases, it vanishes when the system stops for any reason.